# WordPress User Meta Data to Display Multiple Child Pages' Content Inline

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm early in a project using WordPress. I am going to list sets of wordpress child pages ny their parent and have the user select one of each via radio buttons and save to user metadata. I think I can accomplish this.

So if I have a array of these page numbers in user metadata can I display the content of the pages together inline. Is this possible? An alternative would be to display a list of links with wp_list_pages() but I'd really rather show all the content together.

I just wonder if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can loop through the array and get the content for each. If your array of page ids is `$pages`:

```
foreach($pages as $page_id){
    $post = get_post($page_id); 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
    echo $content;  
}
```